# Unable to set data to tableview of window in titanium tab

Tags: android, titanium

My titanium sample code is as follows,

My Main File,
which creates tabs is as follows ,

```
globals.tabs = new AppTabGroup(
            {
                title: 'Waiting',
                icon: 'images/KS_nav_ui.png',
                window: new ListWindow({
                    title: 'Waiting',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    navBarHidden: false,
                    isDone: 0,
                    activity: {
                        onCreateOptionsMenu: function(e) {
                            var menu = e.menu;
                            var menuItem = menu.add({ title: "Add Customer" });
                            menuItem.setIcon("images/ic_menu_add.png");

                            var menuItem1 = menu.add({ title: "Settings" });
                            menuItem1.setIcon("images/ic_menu_add.png");

                            menuItem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                new AddWindow().open();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
            },
            {
                title: 'Done',
                icon: 'images/KS_nav_views.png',
                window: new ListWindow({
                    title: 'Done',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    navBarHidden: false,
                    isDone: 1
                })
            }
        );
```

The new AppTabGroup just creates one tab group and adds these two tabs + it sets currentab

So by default , my Waiting tab remains in focus,

The new ListWindow is described as follows,

```
exports.ListWindow = function(args) {
    var AddWindow = require('ui/AddWindow').AddWindow;
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow(args);
    var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView();

    setTableHandle(tableview);

    var isDone = args.isDone;
    Ti.API.info("isDOne chi value:  " + isDone);

    self.add(tableview);

    tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        createConfirmDialog(e.row.id, e.row.title, isDone).show();
    });

    Ti.App.addEventListener('app:updateTables', function() {
        //tableview.setData(getTableData(isDone));
        tableview.setData(o9Data);
    });

    return self;
};
```

Now by default tableview data (o9Data in above code) ( fetched from httpclient) is always set to second tab,
I changed value of isDone but it's not working

Any help is appreciated

Here is screenshot of second with data ,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solutions to this ,

since this is common code for all tabs and  i used following line,

```
setTableHandle(tableview);
```

which just set's tableview variable for setting data to table,  this get's overridden by last tab and therefore i was not able to add values to first or all(except last) tab.